# Laravel model data foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have the following line `$totalRequests = \App\LoanRequest::all();` which returns all records, Along a model `Applicant` which have `One to Many` relation with `LoanRequest`.

So i can access applicants data with `$totalRequests[0]->applicant->region` for with `foreach()`.

**Question :**

Now i want all the **distinct** `regions` in the `Applicant` or table `applicants` from the `LoanRequest::all()` model and want to push those `regions` to an array which then i can pass to a view.

What i am trying :

```
$totalRequests = \App\LoanRequest::all();
foreach($totalRequests as $applicant){
    $filterMeta = [];
    array_push($applicant->aplicant->region, $filterMeta);      
}
```

It throws:

`Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Applicant::$region has no effect`

Comment: try with `array_push($filterMeta, $applicant->aplicant->region);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the region to the array, you're using the wrong argument order. Also, shouldn't you be initalising the filter meta array outside of the loop?

```
$totalRequests = \App\LoanRequest::all();
$filterMeta = [];
foreach($totalRequests as $applicant){
    array_push($filterMeta, $applicant->aplicant->region);
}
```

Comment: Its working. And how to apply distinct on this data now ?

Comment: Easiest is probably http://php.net/array_unique, or check before pushing if it's already in the array.

Comment: Done !! Thanks ;)

Comment: Laravel should have a `\App\LoanRequest::all()->distinct()->get()` method... to grab only what you need from the database. Worth looking into it.

Comment: Yeah, and just pluck that value as well.